# Pseudo-dicts as properties

Tags: python, methods, nested, nested-class, nested-attributes

I have a Python class `C` which should have two pseudo-`dict`s `a` and `b`. The term pseudo-dicts means that the dictionaries don't actually exist and that they are “recomputed” each time a key is accessed.

In pseudocode this would look like this:

```
class C:
    def a.__getitem__(self, key):
        return 'a'
    def b.__getitem__(self, key):
        return 'b'

>>> c = C()
>>> c.a['foo']
'a'
>>> c.b['bar']
'b'
```

I could implement a class for `a` and `b`, but since both have just a few short methods, I wonder whether there is a more elegant and compact way to do this.

Comment: The question was not precisely articulated and I wasn't sure if there is an answer at all, so I thought it's not worth any reputation. Moreover, this makes it possible for others (at best native speakers) to clarify my question more easily.

Comment: A bit of curiosity. Why do you need this at all? What is the scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just define your own class?

```
class PseudoDict(object):
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.c.somethingmagical()

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = PseudoDict(self)
        self.b = PseudoDict(self)

c = C()
print c.a['foo']
print c.b['bar']
```

I'm not sure where the values for these 'pseudo-dicts' are coming from, so you'll have to update the `__getitem__` method.

Comment: The values from the pseudo-dicts are coming from `C`, so this approach would `PseudoDict` require to have access to “private” variables of `C`.

Comment: @ott, I'm still not sure where the values are coming from, but I updated the example.

Comment: @ott, you could also pass the function to be used to retrieve the value from `C` to the `PseudoDict` constructor, so that `a` and `b` are actually capable of providing different values.

Comment: If PseudoDict is using "private" variables of C (ie tightly coupled) it's probably more appropriate to define PseudoDict inside the scope of C to reflect the tight coupling

Comment: You might want to use a weak reference to `C`, to avoid reference cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
from collections import defaultdict
class C:
    a = defaultdict(lambda:'a')
    b = defaultdict(lambda:'b')

c=C()
print c.a['foo']
print c.b['bar']
```

Or maybe like this for real calculation functions?

```
from collections import defaultdict

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = defaultdict(self.geta)
        self.b = defaultdict(self.getb)
    def geta(self):
        return 'a'
    def getb(self):
        return 'b'

c=C()
print c.a['foo']
print c.b['bar']
```

Comment: They aren't supposed to return constants. Furthermore they should support multiple keys.

Comment: Could you give real example of the use and why the pseudodict is needed?